# How to read the contents of a file with their specific data types and not as string in python?

Tags: python, file, operation

I have a file with `“mark,19,2050.50,Chris,20,2010.40”` as its content.
If I read the file using `open()`, the contents are assigned into the file as `textIOwrapper`. If I split and store it in a list using the delimiter(‘,’ in this case) the list contains the values as strings.

```
For eg : [‘mark’,’19’,’2050.50’, ‘Chris’,’20’,’2010.40’]
```

I need the output to be

```
[‘mark’, 19, 2050.50, ‘Chris’,20,2010.40]
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Should be able to use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929983/3715522

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the specific data types, because you don't know the data types. Everything in a file is assumed to be a string.

You could try to check for some specific cases, but you are better off using a library that already does that for you. Use `panda's` function `pandas.read_csv`.

Comment: What if I have the datatypes of the values in the files

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019283/automatically-type-cast-parameters-in-python) is a SO solution for an autocast. He uses it as a decorator, but basically the function alone would also accomplish what you need. It just tries to cast it as either int, float or if both fail, as a string. 
Nevertheless, if you parse big files that might slow it down. If you have more than the base types it probably won't be as easy.

Answer (score 0):

eval() seems to do the trick for basic data types

Thanks for the suggestions